# Как отправить несколько сообщений в ответ пользователю в telegram боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

То есть пользователь нажимает `/start`, и от бота ему должны прийти два или более отдельных сообщений. Используется `Python` и `pytelegrambotapi`.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def say_hi(message):
    keyboard_level_0 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    ...
    keyboard_level_0.add(menu_button, help_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'some text', reply_markup=keyboard_level_0)
def explains(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'some text-2')
```

Comment: Укажите ваши попытки. Прикрепите код.

Answer (score 0):

просто добавить еще 1 строчку с отправкой

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def say_hi(message):
    keyboard_level_0 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    ...
    keyboard_level_0.add(menu_button, help_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'some text1', reply_markup=keyboard_level_0)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'some text2', reply_markup=keyboard_level_0)
```